Verilog assignment using vectors
I am attempting to assign data from one wire to another wire in Verilog using vector subscripting. This is the simplest implementation that I could think to write to demonstrate the problem I have. Essentially, I have the wire s, and the wire u. Each is 4 bits wide. The issue is that the wire u remains zzzz after assignment from wire s. If I do something like assign s[n] = 1, this works for index n. But, when I assign from wire s to wire u using assign u[3] = s[3] this does not work. u will remain zzzz. Any suggestions?
module test;
wire [3:0] s;
wire [3:0] u;
// assign s = 4'b1111;
assign s[3] = 1;
assign s[2] = 1;
assign s[1] = 1;
assign s[0] = 1;

// These statements work
assign u[3] = 1;
assign u[2] = 0;
assign u[1] = 0;
assign u[0] = 0;

// These statements do not work.
assign u[3] = s[3];
assign u[2] = s[2] & ~|s[3];
assign u[1] = s[1] & ~|s[3:2];
assign u[0] = s[0] & ~|s[3:1];

initial begin
    $display("%d", s[3]);
    $display("%d", s[2]);
    $display("%d", s[1]);
    $display("%d", s[0]);
    $display("%d", s);

    $display("%d", u[3]);
    $display("%d", u[2]);
    $display("%d", u[1]);
    $display("%d", u[0]);
    $display("%d", u);
end
endmodule


One problem is that you have a simulation race condition in your code.  When I run your code on 2 different simulators, I get 2 different results.  I don't see zzzz like you do either.  The race problem is that the $display statements execute at time 0 when the signals are changing values.  You can fix that problem by adding a delay inside the initial block:
initial begin
    #1;
    $display("%d", s[3]);
    $display("%d", s[2]);

Aside from that, you are not following good coding practices.  You should not have multiple continuous assignments to the same wire, such as:
assign u[3] = 1;

assign u[3] = s[3];

Choose one or the other.
You probably should delete these statements:
// These statements work
assign u[3] = 1;
assign u[2] = 0;
assign u[1] = 0;
assign u[0] = 0;


I think you're assuming that these statements are running in a sequential manner. However they are parallel. The assign u[3] = 1 works because it has a defined value. However, in case of assign assign u[3] = s[3], the s[3] is itself not 1 at this moments as its also running in parallel and has not executed yet.

Yes. You are correct about my assumption. That is very helpful. It's there a way assign from s[3] to u[3] that will work?

You can add delay at start of the initial block such as initial begin #10 to give some time for the signals to be set properly.
